# Joomla 1.6 problem

Tags: joomla, standards, joomla-extensions, strict

I recently installed Joomla 1.6 on my XAMPP local server and i got this error message:

> Strict Standards: Declaration of JButtonPopup::fetchId() should be compatible with that of JButton::fetchId() in J:\XAMPP\htdocs\joomla16\libraries\joomla\html\toolbar\button\popup.php on line 78

I tried with XAMPP 1.73 and 1.74 and I get the same message, and when I try to install any extension, I get the "can not create directory" message.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your php.ini file.

Look for:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

And replace with:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT
```

Look for:

```
display_errors = On
```

And replace with:

```
display_errors = Off
```

Make sure that you fine every instance it is possible for those to appear more than once in the file.

Comment: where can i find that php.ini file ??

Comment: php.ini can be in different locations. You may not even have access depending on your hosting. Here is how to find it - http://www.php-scripts.com/20050909/8/

Answer (score 1):

I installed Joomla 1.6 with Gantry framework on EasyPHP 5.3.6 and have the same problems. 
I could avoid these error messages setting the "display_errors" configuration to "Off" in EasyPHP configuration. It works for the moment.